# Wrap any await function that fails often so that it retries itself

Tags: typescript, async-await

I have a codebase that tends to perform calls to an unreliable server.

Because of this, I have gotten in the habit of wrapping sections of my code in:

```
while(true) {
    try {
        let returnVal = await functionCall(param);
        break;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        await delay(1000);
    }
}
```

But as I add more features, such as error formatting and timeouts, this gets incredibly verbose and unweildy.

Can I wrap a generic function somehow (with any return value) so that I can just call

```
let returnVal = retryAwait(functionCall(param));
```

---

I've tried creating a function and passing arguments via a closure:

```
async function retry(fn: Function) {
    while(true) {
        try {
            return await fn();
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            await delay(1000);
        }
    }
}

let returnVal = await retry(function(){return functionCall(param)});
```

And this seems to work, but I want to make sure I am not shooting myself in the foot somewhere? When I start addressing the Promise returning an incorrect value, will I have issues?

Is this the correct solution to my problem?

Comment: IMO you're shooting yourself in the foot by making a messy workaround instead of fixing the problem at its source - try to fix the server if you can.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my server to fix or I'd love to. Is there a cleaner workaround?

Comment: What kind of unreliability are we talking about? Timeouts? Or some specific response codes?

Comment: Mostly timeouts. Sometimes other specific codes. It's a bit of a mess.

Comment: @nbstrong Well maybe then add a check for those inside the catch and only repeat when they happen, and reject for other errors, because if at some point you make a mistake in a call and get 400 Bad request back, you would want to know that it is a mistake on your side. Also consider adding a max repeat amount to the retry call, lets say if it fails N times, you give up or you might end with multiple calls hammering the server. Then you might get rejected for a different reason, the server throttling your calls.

Comment: Yes, this is overly simplified and Ill be adding a timeout and max repeat as well as attempting to handle the errors I can appropriately. Also the delays are reduced in my example for simplicity.

Comment: Okay, but also the error types should be checked to some extent, because repeating on any 4xx error wont change the result, no matter how long you do it, unless the server is really borked beyond belief and returns random error codes.

Comment: Understood, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I presume that you are working on solving this problem for learning purposes, as many promise "retry" functions already exist in community modules/packages.

Obviously, you'd want to handle problematic responses within the callback function that you pass to the `retry` function (using `try/catch`), and try to recover (if possible) before rethrowing and restarting the retry loop after a delay. However, once you reach such an impasse, you'd throw an exception (potentially with some useful data from the response, etc.).

You can modify your function to accept a second argument (another function) to be called in the case of exceptions being thrown:

The second function computes the delay timeout interval before the next retry. It can use contextual information: the exception which was thrown, the current number of tries (count), and the total elapsed time in order to compute the next timeout value (e.g. for [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff)). If you return an interval less than `0`, the retry function stops and returns `undefined`:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKYBsCGBPRAKWAW1ThCgFkBnALkTBEICNUAnASloAUW5CZLUAHgBucGMgB8iAN4BYAFCJELVFBAskYVAHdE3Xv1R4VlRAF4pAqABUYxUlGOpKAGkRESZKmzYBuBQC+CgpQ2AAOqIgAYmCCCkqcmCyYhKaoAB5QqGDIpiqYyAjouOAA1mBw2mAA2gC65oiYYNh1LvGIAErOIOhQDU3YbfJSZvgAdBNhSSk0etOpbOZSXZQ9UP7yIeGRXVAs2ACi6RCoYbAIAMIIWZkNcoqIAPQAVM+I1gAWkRDqKmB99CYrEQcGA7hYMGciGej3aEFI-1ogOYLA2Sheb0+kSgcCgmHQdAYKJBYL46HQhnhOVMlBgkEizGAcBU7i+iGAMBYlD6e1wMPaGEwYQEyCRRNYaKer3ebIyJzO8CQ2g+MAgH0Q2kwpigHx4VXZPEIrMiAANeSbEIx0HAIKVobCHnLTucwLQyhUqhsAhsFBj4m8AILs8DQRUalVqxDwwhhMhQnWRLS3NBYXB0rIsYT4sb+-2IAC0iAAkmDMHRUABzTCwYSJ8UsRD8ZSqdRaZBuBPN3nByAuxs0nFhCLtvMqNQaOkVxqILPoECRUGIE3gNActsmnOKZ55wsl6dhOC0mt1oENptj1uodvGmf4+f9xAgEWNbVs5HAxdkikCKm5PM4jVMBgPpwFgAlOyTPox32Td7S2CJOlUfYjnlF0AAkmmQdBgVGGJBGqKkbigWhdmQ45nUVK5-gyKBajcd8GwAHz0Q1DEEBiJAkH15C1bBIB7UMEC7fZEEEKJEBo7JcmiMAJDwdpgFdaIhiUCtVAAORo2x7DIEikMOciFQQDCcmwlghg4FiDAEQRdlbaxtjEqRmJXVA1yvKR7iUbC+nhUCGgABklKluUQbkkj6UYIhYJkWEIJoTjGD08D8dplRgbCCBYedFi8pQowRPoAGpRgARklJRuzy-Ku1bRpNWA9kwBSirECCB4lAgatIzwJ0jLAXL2hqkK+kFYUrwaaLYvi+kksqFKCzCvEWHWIb8pG9w7E8SL6qAvo1KgTTMm07a8GkPz-jcMaRSuwyXQCVKOvymAwQILaHFExAAsWC8NEfHI3LpK9WqUTAGr6FMcDenSoEemr2qUdr2oUXj+NAXswwyFIwmw-BBoeVGIAEvtwDCFRkFVPErUiFKuFYmzuQhMAK08taXvwchqw+MZkhyXgFsEL6xgAVh+ls-oAcgAZRACATkoSgJdanU9XLXQDhYHgWDwCWoiA9AJbhtrggeDaTDWfpweE7A8FJ8nKcwam3DwQiaMWCwZDZ17XcyMYLr6KQAGYxfHJB83KtbfqQUqAtjyUHu4pR2YIbZF3N3pEAAQjMUYJdc9zkENz2nvTvpHkeJamYrdoEYk9ABGLmrS6eCv86B5A1vLxBsFIFBUAgcQJoA7k4DCRsoBrwIFCAA)

```ts
function delay (timeoutMs: number): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, timeoutMs));
}

type Fn<
  Params extends readonly unknown[] = any[],
  Result = any,
> = (...params: Params) => Result;

type RetryExceptionContext = {
  /** The current number of tries */
  count: number;
  /** The total number of milliseconds since before the first try */
  elapsed: number;
  /** The exception which was thrown from the `try` block */
  exception: unknown;
};

/**
 * A function which computes the next delay interval.
 *
 * - If a negative number is returned, the retry function is stopped,
 * returning a value of `undefined`.
 *
 * - If a positive number is returned, the value is used as the number of milliseconds
 * to wait until the next retry.
 */
type RetryExceptionHandler = Fn<[context: RetryExceptionContext], number | Promise<number>>;

async function retry <F extends Fn>(
  fn: F,
  getNextTimeout: RetryExceptionHandler,
): Promise<ReturnType<F> | undefined> {
  let count = 0;
  const start = performance.now();
  while(true) {
    count += 1;
    try {
      return await fn();
    }
    catch (exception) {
      const elapsed = performance.now() - start;
      const timeout = await getNextTimeout({count, elapsed, exception});
      if (timeout < 0) return undefined;
      await delay(timeout);
    }
  }
}

async function example () {
  async function unpredictable (): Promise<string> {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) return 'Success';
    throw new Error('Fail');
  }

  const result = await retry(unpredictable, (context) => {
    if (context.count > 3) return -1;
    return 1000;
  });

  if (typeof result !== 'undefined') {
    result // string
  }
  else {
    result // undefined
    // you decided to stop it
  }
}
```

---

Edit: Here's a variation on the above with an additional `state` parameter for arbitrary data that can be used in both callback functions: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-GUqnUWmQblnj-NA8gefvplNcDCCJXx3FQ1A0TUz0aRB13QEBIkZRA43ANAjRfOMt0UfEd33I8oLCOANVga8ZTpO8H1A59UFfWNIhguDf3BO1GlDA1+XpBDFWVARVVyHcJSDTAq3BakYGld95z6UD9gwzMtgiGFzSOT08wACSaZB0FYe5HmeV5slyGE4V+f5WGRMFCwxBpPm+YzEVM7AQXMsBynRTFzHaGJBGqVUbl5BT9iU3NvSualXm0+sJFqNw2LvAAfPRo0MQQYsxLt5BDbBIC-IcEA-fZEDiHE7heTJ9I+WEbIRAD7Mc1FnMhDEhiUKISreAzPOqZtUFbWoJCGCQ8HaYB82iJrEDPVQADlXlsewyFoXYAuOIKEDUnJNJYe4+vaLqGmkAJmMQO4hg4BKDAEQRdmfaxtkEKIpHi5DUFQqipGxJRNL6blqQaAAGZ1VVNdVHkBBoAV1FhCCaE4xkhPA-HaX1RKMPY4MWd6lHHUgfoAalGABGZ0lE-DHMY-Z9GmDIThrwLqEZxJQggZ8cnjHPAcy9BB0faMnAb6a1bSosHWAhqGtVhyp4b3YGknWHnMb59w7E8PpRkwKm+gmqBpsyWaVbwaRvqgNwBbtE3ls5sA3C6gJ6bJpQYCZAhlYcArEF+xYKI0YSUM1Kiicx9XBL6NAsGwZ25qgO3MaZxnAmCdLKEyiBsp-DIUjCTT8G5nFQnkttnlGUnECwU0ADUNzgh1SOdTsE6UDKstAb9h3AMIVGQf1HhTSJaZ07qjv7079D4C7TRZMAzze+XFeSHIGnIJ4STGOfCkIeGA8d-BV7d36xgAVk9p9vYAcjuEAIBOShKBPgOurGUuoAr2DIlGVeA7DCNT10A4WB4Fg8AnyiIJdAJ9o5My5AgIGmoqwwA3AXAeCC9qP2flXRAk1MCTTrpsHEs9ui9H6BrPK4c24dy7pgHubg8A+VeIsCwMh5a4lxIgKG6REAAGZmSskoPLLe1DrivDGEbRAUh2FHzAkgXchNGHMNXrwaCldxRwDgONfIUBeFOxoZkMY98UGKJEaMPeABOQ+5NvZSIDl7JA+Nfq2Nrm4GBsB4FDzSg7J2ecSBMhMGsRAABCMwowT5PResgMBDDmbeIIUw4GE8zztFji8dAAhwlk0iX0aJwS-bIBkYgbApBFwQHEELfi-4wj3nUTiJmTMgA)

Comment: Any specific promise retry functions from packages you would recommend?

Comment: @nbstrong Here are a couple: [`vercel/async-retry`](https://github.com/vercel/async-retry), [`sindresorhus/p-retry`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-retry)